# How will you fix the direction of the lines of force due to circular current?

Tags: experimental-physics, homework-and-exercises

I have tried to learn it myself but I was unable to understand. Can you please explain it in detaails with simple example.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

By [lines of force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force), do you mean the magnetic field? If so, you could determine the direction of the B-field by right-hand  rule.

[image]

The reason is that a current element flowing up will create a B-field circulating out of the screen on the wire's left, and into the screen on the right's right. This direction is chosen by convention.

[image]

Wrap the wire into a loop (making it flows counterclockwise), we find that the B-field will point into the screen outside of the loop,

[image]

and out of the screen inside the loop

[image]

Summing up all elements (Biot-Savart law) we will find that the B-field should look like

[image]

(Picture source: http://frank.mtsu.edu/~phys2020/Lectures/L12-L18/L17/Current_Loops/current_loops.html; Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

A circular current, running counter-clockwise when viewed from above, induces a magnetic field whose field lines point mostly up through the center of the loop and then curl around to point down outside the loop.  A clockwise current's magnetic field lines point the opposite direction.

Here is a picture from [this](http://lempel.pagesperso-orange.fr/rappels_physique_uk.htm) source
[image: magnetic field lines]